# Is there a way to use PowerShell in Azure Functions to export results to SQL Server?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell

Looking at serverless PowerShell running in an Azure Function, is there a way to direct the output to an SQL server table?

From what I have seen, I have not seen a way to send output to SQL itself.  Powershell can perform many tasks, send back status results, but not direct thousands of rows to a table?

Would someone be able to tell me what keywords to use to research this if it is possible?  I don't need someone to give me the code to solve it, I just want to make sure I'm not wasting my time trying to accomplish something that isn't supported.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy switch that would just redirect the entire output stream to a SQL server (if this is what you are looking for), but you can use the [SqlServer module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer) to write data to SQL tables.